# Sudoku solver Python algorithm clarification needed

Tags: python, backtracking, sudoku

I have built a sudoku solver backtracking algorithm in python just to find out it does not work. I looked at examples on the internet and saw that there is only one thing which they are doing differently, compared to mine. I changed my code accordingly and my program is now working fine.

**Here is the working code:**

```
sudoku = []
next_empty_pos = [0,0]

# Check if the number is already used in the given row
def valid_in_row(number,row):
    for i in range(9):
        if(sudoku[row][i] == number):
            return False
    return True

# Check if the number is already used in the given column
def valid_in_col(number,col):
    for i in range(9):
        if(sudoku[i][col] == number):
            return False;
    return True;

# Check if the number is already used in the given 3x3 box
def valid_in_box(number,row,col):
    # Find where 3x3 row and col starts
    col_start = col-col%3
    row_start = row-row%3
    # Loop through the 3 columns and 3 rows
    for i in range(3):
        for z in range(3):
            if(sudoku[i+row_start][z+col_start] == number):
                return False
    return True

# Check if the position is valid for the given number by checking all three conditions above
def position_valid(number,row,col):
    return valid_in_row(number,row) and valid_in_col(number,col) and valid_in_box(number,row,col)

# Find if there are any empty cells left and assign the next empty cell
def empty_position_exists():
    for row in range(9):
        for col in range(9):
            if(sudoku[row][col] == 0):
                global next_empty_pos
                next_empty_pos = [row,col]
                return True
    return False

# Solve the sudoku
def solve_sudoku():

    # If there are no more empty cells, we are finished
    if(not empty_position_exists()):
        return True

    row=next_empty_pos[0]
    col=next_empty_pos[1]

    # Try numbers from 1
    for posssible_number in range(1,10):

        if(position_valid(posssible_number,row,col)):

            sudoku[row][col] = posssible_number

            # If the next function call evalutes to true, then this should be true as well
            if(solve_sudoku()):
                return True

            # If the above did not work then, set the number back to 0 (unassgined)
            sudoku[row][col] = 0

    # Return false if none of the numbers were good
    return False
```

The difference to my original code was that I was passing `next_empty_pos[0]` and `next_empty_pos[1]` directly in my `solve_sudoku` function and not declaring them as seperate `row` and `col` variables outside of the for loop.

**My function looked like this:**

```
# Solve the sudoku
def solve_sudoku():

    # If there are no more empty cells, we are finished
    if(not empty_position_exists()):
        return True

    # Try numbers from 1
    for posssible_number in range(1,10):

        if(position_valid(posssible_number,next_empty_pos[0],next_empty_pos[1])):

            sudoku[next_empty_pos[0]][next_empty_pos[1]] = posssible_number

            # If the next function call evalutes to true, then this should be true as well
            if(solve_sudoku()):
                return True

            # If the above did not work then, set the number back to 0 (unassgined)
            sudoku[next_empty_pos[0]][next_empty_pos[1]] = 0

    # Return false if none of the numbers were good
    return False
```

Could someone explain why my version was not working?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`empty_position_exists` changes `next_empty_pos`.  When `solve_sudoku` calls itself recursively, `empty_position_exists` is called from the recursive invocation, changing `next_empty_pos`.  The result is that when you access those values after the recursive call returns, they have changed.  That's why the two versions behave differently.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Thank you!